# Lithium Ion Battery - Testing & Self Discharge

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, safety, testing

It is suggested and commonly understood that if Li-ion batteries drop below a certain threshold that we consider the cell(s) unstable and untrustworthy with a loss in cell capacity and that increased risk of an internal short circuit. This can be particularly disheartening as when we purchase powerbanks and phones on the uncommon occasion they are supplied within the 0-2V region. Historically I have been using float voltage measurements and monitoring Li-ion battery self-discharge rates to determine good cells from bad. **My question is whether this form of testing is a reasonable approach and safe, particularly on cells that were discharged to as far as 0V or say 1.7V?** Note I tend to look for a self-discharge of around 20mV (0.02V) within a week or two from a charge. Stepping up state of charge in intervals; 3V then 3.4V then 3.6V before accepting the cell(s). I have observed cells drop by as much as 0.5 to 1V within a month, these cells are discarded appropriately.

Comment: I would call that a reasonable test, what your indirectly testing is if the graphite electrode has degraded to a point where it can cause leakage paths / shorts through the separator. If there no self discharge, then its likely that any damage was to a small enough threshold that it does not risk shorting itself out..

Comment: Below 2.5V the action required is simple, just replace the cell because it _will_ have suffered damage.